# When selecting records between 2 dates, what impact will encounter when I use "OR" over an "AND"?

Tags: mysql

An example

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date>=01012018 OR date<=31012018`

Using "AND"

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE date>=01012018 AND date<=31012018`

How will my records be affected?

Comment: OR will return all results, as if you had no condition. AND will do the right thing. This should be obvious. What actual problem are you facing?

Comment: The OR will select all records, and the AND will select just those between the two dates.

Comment: I have a situation where the previous developer used OR to select records between the first day of the month AND the last day of the month but instead of combining the 2 condition with an AND, they used OR which was returning incorrect results and these results were always used as correct

Comment: If you need help debugging the previous developer's code, I suggest including that code in the question. Otherwise, there's not much we can do, and not much point posting a question here.

Comment: Sounds like a nasty mess you have to clean up though how this got through test is beyond me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a big impact.

When you use "condition AND condition" the query will return only the matching results (in your case, only results where the date is >= than 01012018 AND date is <= 31012018, like 10012018, 20012018, 15012018, etc).

If you use "condition OR condition", it will return the results where the date is >= 01012018 (like 02012018, 20012018, 15022018, 30122018, etc) OR the date is <= 31012018 (like 01012000, 15022015, 17052017, etc) -> basically, all the results.